# Register Custom Application to be Selectable for Handling HTTP(S) in Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows, browser

I searched through the web, but I didn't get the right advice.

I'm looking for a proper way to register my custom (C#, .NET) application in WINDOWS 7 to be recognized for HTTP and HTTPS URL Program and can be selected as default. I've found several sites telling me how to register a custom protocol, but none of them worked for me and http.

The menu I want the application to show up is: Control Panel -> Default Programs -> Associate a file type or protocol with a program -> Protocols (HTTPS)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The registration can be performes as follows:
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\BrowSelURL]
    @="BrowSel URL"
    "FriendlyTypeName"="BrowSel URL"
    "URL Protocol"=""
    "EditFlags"=dword:00000002

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\BrowSelURL\DefaultIcon]
@="[TARGETDIR]BrowSel.exe,0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\BrowSelURL\shell]
@="open"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\BrowSelURL\shell\open]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\BrowSelURL\shell\open\command]
@="[TARGETDIR]\BrowSel.exe \"%1\""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\BROWSEL.EXE]
@="Browser Selector"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\BROWSEL.EXE\Capabilities]
"ApplicationIcon"="[TARGETDIR]\BrowSel.exe,0"
"ApplicationName"="BrowSel"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\BROWSEL.EXE\Capabilities\StartMenu]
"StartMenuInternet"="BROWSEL.EXE"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\BROWSEL.EXE\Capabilities\URLAssociations]
"http"="BrowSelURL"
"https"="BrowSelURL"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\BROWSEL.EXE\DefaultIcon]
@="[TARGETDIR]\BrowSel.exe,0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\BROWSEL.EXE\shell]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\BROWSEL.EXE\shell\open]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\BROWSEL.EXE\shell\open\command]
@="[TARGETDIR]\BrowSel.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications]
"BrowSel"="Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\BROWSEL.EXE\Capabilities"
```

NB: The format here is just a description, there may be some characters to escape.

And the last line registers the application as selectable in the menu of the specific Protocol.